# How to fetch data from JSON and show it in table cell view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

This is my Json returned from webservices. 
How can I fetch data of watch id and show it in table view cell?

> [{"0":"17","watch_id":"17","1":"127","msg_id":"127","2":"u2a","type":"u2a","3":"17","4":"333333","gcmid":"333333","5":"Chhh","message":"Chhh","6":"1418887791","add_time":"1418887791"}]

Comment: i am using NSarray but my app is crashed

Comment: what is error?? can you post it

Comment: r u got the answer my friend..

Comment: Till now not getting the issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this`[[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"msg_id"];` you will able to retrive value stored at msg_id key

Answer (score 0):

Below line is to get response data

```
 id objects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                 options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                   error:&deserializingError];
```

And following code is for getting jSON data from the response

```
for (NSDictionary *dictTemp in arr) {

    NSString *watchID = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"watch_id"];
    NSString *msgID = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"msg_id"];
    NSString *type = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"type"];
    NSString *gcmID = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"gcmid"];
    NSString *msg = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"message"];
    NSString *time = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"add_time"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you don't know how is your response is, you can use a site like, http://json.parser.online.fr/*

which formats JSON response pretty readable.

Here what I can see from your response,

[image]

response is in form of `NSArray` contains `NSDictionary`.

So you can access your response like this,

```
NSArray *watches = response;
NSLog(@"%@", [[watches firstObject] valueForKey:@"watch_id"]);
```

To iterate each dictionary inside array, you can use a loop, like this,

```
NSArray *watches = response;
for(NSDictionary *watch in watches) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [watch valueForKey:@"watch_id"]);
}
```

*there's many sites available - Google, `JSON format online`.